# How to enable WYSIWYG in a text field summary?

Tags: 7, entities, wysiwyg

I have a body field (Text field with summary) with WYSIWYG CKeditor enabled.

However, the "summary" part of the field lacks a WYSIWYG editor.
How can I enable it?

Comment: Under your content type -> manage fields for the summary field you can enable text processing to be filtered text (user selects input format).

Comment: @zarsiwala, you should post this as an answer to the question; it'll help your reputation and the organization of the site.

Comment: Here's a recent blog post that solves this problem: [Drupal 7: How to Add a WYSIWYG Editor to a "Text with Summary" Field](http://theunraveler.com/blog/2012/drupal-7-how-add-wysiwyg-editor-text-summary-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module's logic acts on text fields with input formats, if you want to explicitly target a form element by its ID you can use the [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/CKEditor) module instead.

Answer (score 2):

Under your content type -> manage fields for the summary field you can enable text processing to be filtered text (user selects input format). Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems to refer to the main field, not to the summary. At least, I have it already set to be filtered and have the WYSIWYG editor only in the main field (not in the summary).

Answer (score 2):

I had created my own summary field in CCK. I use the CKeditor and this only worked after I realised I had to configure the field as a multiline text area and not as a single line text field.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried WYSIWYG module version 7.x-2.x-dev with CKEditor (the editor, not the Drupal module), and it actually worked -- the summary field now displays with a wysiwyg editor instead of the plain textarea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [wysiwyg module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) you can enable/disable this in the wysiwyg profile settings. It’s in the fieldset at the bottom: «Basic settings - Enable on summary fields».