# Enable wysiwyg on textarea summary field

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

Anyone know how I can enable the WYSIWYG editor for the textarea summary field in D8? I have a "body" field on my news content type set to "Text (formatted, long, with summary)" but only the main textarea gets the WYSIWYG editor while the summary field is just a standard textarea.

[image]

The summary field does support rich text, presumably using the same text format as the main textarea, but it's not clear since CKEditor is not there.

Note there's a similar question asked but it's from 2011: [How to enable WYSIWYG in a text field summary?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10961/how-to-enable-wysiwyg-in-a-text-field-summary)

Comment: Good question!  The "similar question" you mention is for Drupal 7, so that doesn't help us.